# JavaFX on Docker Container

Tags: docker, javafx, jar

I'm currently trying to integrate my perfectly working toDoList.jar file into a docker container(OpenJDK14 on linux alpine). I'm able to build the image which also copys JavaFX into the image, but when I try to run the container I get the following error:

***Error***

```
C:\Users\jkcar\IdeaProjects\toDoList>docker run todolist
Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
java.lang.module.FindException: Module javafx.controls not found
```

***Dockerfile***

```
FROM openjdk:14-alpine

COPY library/javafx-sdk-14.0.2.1 /JavaFX

COPY out/artifacts/toDoList_jar/toDoList.jar /JavaAPP/toDoList.jar

ENTRYPOINT ["java" , "--module-path" , "/JavaFX/javafx-sdk-14.0.2.1/lib" , "--add-modules" , "javafx.controls,javafx.fxml" , "-jar" , "/JavaAPP/toDoList.jar"]
```

I figure that the error has something to do with my ENTRYPOINT command but I am having trouble determining what the error in my command is. Does anyone have any recommendations/advice/tips that might get this to work?

Comment: Do you just need a leading `/` on the `--module-path` argument? Note you might need a base image other than the alpine version (I'm not sure it has a native graphics toolkit).

Comment: @James_D I just tried it with a `/` at the `--module-path` argument, but I'm still getting the same error. I'll check out other base images and get back to you whether those work or not. Do you have any recommendations?

Comment: Changing the base image won't fix the problem you posted. Fix one thing at a time.

Comment: Okay, in that case do you have any other recommendations?

Comment: Only the obvious: check it works on a linux host machine, check the contents of the `/JavaFX` folder on the container are as expected, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up solving the following by re-routing how I copied my JavaFX SDK and toDoList.jar. Here is the adjusted section of the Dockerfile.

```
COPY library/javafx-sdk-14.0.2.1 javafx-sdk-14.0.2.1
COPY out/artifacts/toDoList_jar/toDoList.jar toDoList.jar

ENTRYPOINT java --module-path /javafx-sdk-14.0.2.1/lib --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml -jar toDoList.jar -Dprism.verbose=true
```